# Warning session start - cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Tags: apache-2.2, php, login, session

I'm having a slight problem and I hope you may be able to help me. I'm not a programmer or a coder but I just want to fix some troubles with my project.

**Here is the context.** I need to install and use one of my project (eCommerce website) offline on my notebook (HP - Windows7). So I have already installed Appserv and import the databases. I also copy paste all the files in the www/name of the project folders. The website is in PHP and Javascript. No CMS and the CSS templates have been designed internally.

I started the website offline using localhost and I opened the admin log in page. I entered my Log in and password and I got the following message:

*"
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\AppServ\www\thailema_v2\controller\admin\login.php:1) in C:\AppServ\www\thailema_v2\controller\admin\login.php on line 3

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\AppServ\www\thailema_v2\controller\admin\login.php:1) in C:\AppServ\www\thailema_v2\controller\admin\login.php on line 18
"*

So I couldn't reach my admin page and relaunch offline the functions I need. I have already read and tried some proposed solutions here but it did not change and there are some solutions I couldn't figure out as I'm not a professional programmer.

**Anyway here is the code of the page:**

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
$path = '../';
include_once($path."include/check_lang.inc.php");
include_once($path."include/connect.php");
include_once($path."include/login.class.php");

$objLogin=new Login();
$check=$objLogin->getLogin($_POST["customer_username"],$_POST["customer_password"]);

if($check){
    $url = $path."add_booking_info.php?lang=".$lang;
}else{
    $url = $path."payment_step1.php?error=yes&lang=".$lang;
}

header("Location: ".$url);
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

So what I want to do is to log in the admin pages and use all the admin functions but at the moment I cannot even access the admin index pages because of that error. 
Thanks a lot for your help and support...

Olivier

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure there is absolutely **no** whitespace before `<?php`
2. Put `session_start()` before `ob_start()` instead of after it.
3. If that fails, try commenting out the session_start() as one of your includes might already be starting the session, like so:     `/** session_start(); **/`

Comment: Hi Joe. Thanks for your message... I did the modifications and restart apache server but I still got the same message. There is no whitespace before <?php

Comment: Still getting *both* errors? (ie, about the session cache, *and* about modifying header info) or just one? if just one, which one?

Comment: Still both errors 
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\AppServ\www\thailema_v2\controller\admin\login.php:1) in C:\AppServ\www\thailema_v2\controller\admin\login.php on line 3

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\AppServ\www\thailema_v2\controller\admin\login.php:1) in C:\AppServ\www\thailema_v2\controller\admin\login.php on line 18

Comment: I wonder if one of your includes is already starting the session... try commenting out the session_start and see if that does anything, at least to the first error.

Comment: What do you mean by commenting out the session? Sorry for the question... but I'm not a programmer...

Comment: Updated answer to show what i mean, since the formatting will not work right if i do it as a comment.

Comment: thanks for the update... but still the same message

Answer (score -1):

I had the same similar problem. When I uploaded from my pc to my online webhost i got the same error. I removed any whitespace, put the session_start at the top of the file, but with no result. Then looked at my php version running on my localhost. And it was 5.4 and online it was 5.3. I updated my webhost version from 5.3 to 5.4 and my problem was gone.